# Why does my C++ code fail to delete all nodes in my BST?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

This is supposed to traverse a BST and delete every node, including the root node.  However, at the end, I get the message "root still has a left node."  Why aren't all nodes deleted?

```
void deleteTree()
{   
    deleteNode(root);
    if(root->right)
        cout << "root still has a right node" << endl;
    if(root->left)
        cout << "root still has a left node" << endl;
    root = 0;

}   

void deleteNode(node *p) 
{   
    if(p->left) 
    {   
        deleteNode(p->left);
        p->left = 0;
    }   
    if(p->right) 
    {   
        deleteNode(p->right);
        p->right = 0;
    }   

    cout << "Deleting node containing " << p->data << endl;
    delete p;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your are deleting `p` at the end (`root`) and then trying to access its contents in `deleteTree()`, where `root` no longer points to allocated memory. The result is going to be undefined.

Comment: Why is it that when it checks the right node, it doesn't find anything, but when it checks the left node it finds something?

Comment: Because `root` is just pointing to garbage memory. Other results could include left only, both, neither, or a crash.

Answer (score 2):

You're deleting `root`. And then your code is trying to access memory where it was.

You're well into undefined-behaviour land there.

Answer (score 2):

You should not dereference `root` after you delete it in `deleteNode`. Use a debugger to inspect why `root->left` is non-null.

Comment: +1 for debugger suggestion, though I think he'll find that it is, in fact, null when the function returns.

Comment: ‘root‘ is certainly deleted, but there must be something else at ‘root->left‘; maybe sniffing around that address with the debugger will reveal something...

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at `root->left` after you've already deleted root, making it avalable for use in a new allocated block.

Answer (score -1):

I would simply change the tree itself, it would be easier to deal with it then:

```
struct Node
{
  Node(data_type data): mLeft(), mRight(), mData(data) {}
  Node(const Node& rhs): mLeft(), mRight(), mData(rhs.mData)
  {
    if (rhs.mLeft.get()) mLeft.reset(new Node(*rhs.mLeft));
    if (rhs.right.get()) mRight.reset(new Node(*rhs.mRight));
  }
  Node& operator=(Node rhs)
  {
    this->swap(rhs);
    return *this;
  }
  ~Node() { }

  void swap(Node& rhs)
  {
    using std::swap;
    swap(mLeft, rhs.mLeft);
    swap(mRight, rhs.mRight);
    swap(mData, rhs.mData);
  }

  Node* left() const { return mLeft.get(); }
  void left(std::auto_ptr<Node> node) { mLeft= node; }

  Node* right() const { return mRight.get(); }
  void right(std::auto_ptr<Node> node) { mRight = node; }

  data_type& data() { return mData; }
  const data_type& data() const { return mData; }

private:
  std::auto_ptr<Node> mLeft;
  std::auto_ptr<Node> mRight;
  data_type mData;
};
```

By being Object-Oriented, each Node is now responsible for the memory it handles. Also, using `std::auto_ptr` in the interface makes it clear that it takes ownership.

Note that it's been tailored for deep-copying, any other approach requiring `boost::shared_ptr` or equivalent. And yes `std::auto_ptr` leaves you dealing with copying by yourself, no magic there.

This design is much cleaner than using a plain `C-struct` with everyone being able to manipulate the resources. You still have full access to the underlying data via the accessor... but THEY take care not to invoke undefined behavior...

Of course, you can still crash it down:

```
Node& node = ...
delete node.left(); // haha
```

But if C++ may protect against unintended issues, it leaves the door open to evil code.